# Invisible ink pt. 2

Tags: cipher, steganography

I­­ was­­­­­ browsing­­­­ through­ stackoverflow­­­­ meta­­­­, and I found a new way to hide text.

Have fun!

Hint: After you find the ink, there's another tiny layer. Answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> %AD?

I found this by

> copying and pasting the text of the question into a text file, whereupon some mysterious dashes appeared in the first line,

like this:

> I-- was----- browsing---- through- stackoverflow---- meta----, and I found a new way to hide text.

These new characters form

> a pattern of 254144. They're not Morse code, because `----` isn't a valid Morse symbol; translating numbers to letters, BEDADD doesn't make too much sense; the OP says it's meant to be a hex code, so using [this table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) to convert each pair to a character, it seems to come out as **%AD**.

Seems to be a reference to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345752) Meta.SO post (spoilers, obviously), which I found by searching for *[the answer to this puzzle]* on Meta.SO.

Comment: A tiny layer...

Comment: @bleh Did I not find the right tiny layer?

Comment: No, but just you need to look at the tags

Comment: It's not Bacon.

Comment: Much simpler, simple of the simple

Comment: Hint, stackoverflow meta might have some answers

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, and what @bleh is referring too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254123/one-man-bugtracker/254144#254144 (or along that line)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Bleh said it on meta, not main site.

Comment: Ok, well you found the important part, so the rest is that it is in hex

Comment: @bleh Like that?

Comment: No, the percent indicates a character, # is for colors, So it shouldbe %AD, unicode/ ISO or whatever for the soft hyphen

Comment: @bleh Like *that*?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think you're still missing one layer of interpretation.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, that's the answer, now find the SO meta post.

Comment: @bleh I think I found it.

Comment: @MOehm Yes.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: As a sidenote, this is also way to bypass 15characters and not have 10 trailing periods

Comment: @ble Oo!­­­­­­­­